# Flutter API to record video

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

Flutter has no way to record video of the Flutter App.

I tried all the following, all have majors drawbacks that brings to ask this question

#### Using repaintBoundary

This method has 2 major drawbacks:

1. It draws blank white boxes on PlatformViews and WebViews (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25306 and Update 30 June https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83856 it is in progress this quarter)
2. Bitmaps need to be sent back to the Native platform for encoding into mp4. (Using OpenGL)

#### Using native platform

Flutter exposes the [getBitmap](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/platform/android/io/flutter/embedding/engine/FlutterJNI.java#L963) API that is meant be used on the Native Platform to capture a screenshot of the Running hosted Flutter App but this has 2 major drawbacks

1. It must run on UIThread so the FlutterApp is blocked, so the video is recording a blocked UI
2. This method is very slow. Sometimes up to 100 ms per frame depending on the screen content.

#### Recording the entire screen?

Using MediaRecorder that's possible but we want to:

1. Record the app only, not the entire screen
2. Recording the entire screen requires special permission from user

#### Drawing a canvas of the FlutterView in the Native platform?

This draws black screen because FlutterView is a SurfaceView and bitmap cannot be obtained as it was drawn on the different thread.

#### Use PixelCopy?

This API is only availabe on >= API 24

Does FLutter Expose an API to record Bitmaps continuously in the background **not** on the Main UI thread . (Or a video recording API but that's too much to ask)

Keywords: getBitmap, screenshot, bitmap, uithread, background, record, recording, screen shot, main thread, flutterview, surfaceview, video, mp4, mediarecorder, opengl, mediamuxer, mediaencoder